# In Android, how to check whether the text of a button, which is a date selected by datepicker, is valid date or not?

Tags: android

There are a "Date" button and a "Submit" on my activity. 
When I click on "Date"  button, a date picker is shown.The selected date becomes the text of the "Date" button.

On the click of "Submit" button, the text on the "Date" button gets stored in a sqlite database.

I just want a validation on click of "Submit" button that the text of "Date" button is a valid date.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: what do you mean by valid? check if it is in the past?

Comment: edited. I just want a validation code to check whether the text of "Date" button is in proper date format(i.e yyyy-MM-dd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
  public static boolean isValidDate(String inDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    try {
      dateFormat.parse(inDate.trim());
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

use it as:

```
System.out.println(isValidDate(your_string));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the date is matched with your desired date pattern or not.
Check this out:
[Date Validation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416595/date-validation-in-android)