# Date Validation not woking

Tags: android, validation, date

In my android application have 2 edit text field those are taking from the date and last date, I am trying to check whether the date is valid or invalid I tried using this code but it is not working.. where is the error i cant find please help me to correct the code

```
String fromdate,todate;
    private Matcher matcher;
    private static final String DATE_PATTERN =
            "(0?[1-9]|1[012]) [/.-] (0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) [/.-] ((19|20)\\d\\d)";
```

search button Onclick code

```
advsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fromdate=fromed.getText().toString();
                todate=toed.getText().toString();

                matcher = Pattern.compile(DATE_PATTERN).matcher(fromdate);
                matcher = Pattern.compile(DATE_PATTERN).matcher(todate);


      if (!matcher.matches()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Date!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

boolean class

```
 public boolean validate(String date){

        matcher = pattern.matcher(date);

        if(matcher.matches()){

            matcher.reset();

            if(matcher.find()){

                String day = matcher.group(1);
                String month = matcher.group(2);
                int year = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));

                if (day.equals("31") &&
                        (month.equals("4") || month .equals("6") || month.equals("9") ||
                                month.equals("11") || month.equals("04") || month .equals("06") ||
                                month.equals("09"))) {
                    return false; // only 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 has 31 days
                } else if (month.equals("2") || month.equals("02")) {
                    //leap year
                    if(year % 4==0){
                        if(day.equals("30") || day.equals("31")){
                            return false;
                        }else{
                            return true;
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(day.equals("29")||day.equals("30")||day.equals("31")){
                            return false;
                        }else{
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: if you know exactly how the user enters a date (in what format, such as MM-dd-YYYY) then you can validate with just 3 lines of code https://stackoverflow.com/a/226920/3999808

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416595/date-validation-in-android

Comment: @nilesh i checked that code but boolean class is not used there

Comment: @angelina https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528094/7666442

Comment: tried `DateTimeKeyListener`?

Comment: @ pskink no i didnt tried

Comment: how to use DateTimeKeyListener

Comment: when you call validate method.

Comment: i didnt called, where did i call?

Comment: which format to insert date into edittext box.

Answer (score 0):

make separate class for data validation like below ..

```
public class DateValidator {

private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;

private static final String DATE_PATTERN =
        "(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/((19|20)\\d\\d)";

public DateValidator() {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(DATE_PATTERN);
}

/**
 * Validate date format with regular expression
 *
 * @param date date address for validation
 * @return true valid date fromat, false invalid date format
 */
public boolean validate(final String date) {

    matcher = pattern.matcher(date);

    if (matcher.matches()) {

        matcher.reset();

        if (matcher.find()) {

            String day = matcher.group(1);
            String month = matcher.group(2);
            int year = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));

            if (day.equals("31") &&
                    (month.equals("4") || month.equals("6") || month.equals("9") ||
                            month.equals("11") || month.equals("04") || month.equals("06") ||
                            month.equals("09"))) {
                return false; // only 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 has 31 days
            } else if (month.equals("2") || month.equals("02")) {
                //leap year
                if (year % 4 == 0) {
                    if (day.equals("30") || day.equals("31")) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (day.equals("29") || day.equals("30") || day.equals("31")) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

then after on button click put this below code ..

```
 fromdate = et.getText().toString();
            todate = et2.getText().toString();
            DateValidator dateValidator=new DateValidator();
            if (dateValidator.validate(fromdate)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Valid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"InValid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

and edittext enter data format like  dd/mm/yyyy.

more information for format refer this link
http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-date-with-regular-expression/